# How can i link urdf file of turtlebot arm with turtlebot?

Tags: robotic-arm, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to attach turtlebot arm with turtlebot but i am having problem linking these urdf, Can someone provide me a list of steps of instruction to link these parts?
Links to the packages
https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_arm
https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228055/how-can-i-link-urdf-file-of-turtlebot-arm-with-turtlebot?/) by [Asaad Irfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23193/asaad-irfan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2016-03-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wjvh](https://answers.ros.org/users/22783/wjvh/) on 2016-04-30**:
I'm also having an issue with this. Adding the code snippet found in the github readme to the "xacro-macro-magic" URDF which I assume is turtlebot_library.urdf.xacro doesn't make the turtlebot + arm appear in rviz when roslaunch turtlebot_arm_moveit_config turtlebot_arm_moveit.launch is run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the [turtlebot arm installation tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_arm/Tutorials/indigo/Installation), section 1.5 "Add your arm to your turtlebot". As explained there, you need to add a turtlebot_arm macro to your URDF, and set origin for the arm base relative to the base_link of your robot.

**UPDATE**

[Here](https://github.com/corot/thorp/blob/master/thorp_bringup/urdf/thorp.urdf.xacro#L58) is an example of how to integrate the turtlebot  arm in a robot: attach a white and black arm  at <0.10914 0.0295 0.0284> relative to the plate_top_link; use standard turtlebot_gripper. If you have instead a pincher_gripper, flip the true/false in the _gripper parameters.

**UPDATE2**

Here's  the example of the previous link:

```
 <turtlebot_arm parent="plate_top_link" color="White" gripper_color="Black"
                pincher_gripper="false" turtlebot_gripper="true">
   <origin xyz="0.10914 0.0295 0.0284"/>
 </turtlebot_arm>
```

either pincher_gripper or turtlebot_gripper must be true. For the rotation, as you can see attribute rpy is missing, so the arm should appear with default alignment, if all the joints are set to 0. You can set a different orientation adding

```
rpy="${M_PI/2} 0.0 0.0"
```

to origin for a 90 degrees rotation. Can you post a picture to see what do you mean more precisely?

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2016-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wjvh](https://answers.ros.org/users/22783/wjvh/) on 2016-05-03**:
Thanks jorge. Do you have an example turtlebot description file for this as I've tried the above with no luck. Does the turtlebot_arm arm.launch file automatically call the combined turtlebot+arm model in rviz if you follow the above instructions? Cheers!

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2016-05-03**:
Answer updated with an example.  Nop,  arm.launch just starts an arm floating in the void

**Comment by [wjvh](https://answers.ros.org/users/22783/wjvh/) on 2017-06-03**:
Hi Jorge - have come back to this and made some progress, but my arm appears rotated 90 degrees and the gripper appears wrong because I'm not able to find the _gripper parameters you describe. I'm using the standard turtlebot_arm repo not the corot repo. In which file are these parameters? Thanks!

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2017-06-05**:
see update 2

**Comment by [wjvh](https://answers.ros.org/users/22783/wjvh/) on 2017-07-05**:
Thanks Jorge, getting there! This works but I've got 2 problems (1) in rviz there's a "no transform from gripper_link to base_footprint" error and this is causing (2) turtlebot_arm_kinect_calibration to output "gripper_link passed to lookupTransform argument source_frame does not exist". Any ideas?